# What is the opposite of _.remove

Tags: lodash

```
    _.remove($scope.posts, post);
```

I', using _.remove to remove items from an array using lodash. But how do I add objects again? So what is the opposite of _.remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_.remove removes an item from an array, now since you want an opposite of the remove which can be push, there is no _.push available. So, i think it's better to use native push function.
here are few things you can consider:

```
var posts = [{a:1},{b:3},{f:3}];
var post = {a:1};

_.remove(posts, post); // posts = [{b:3},{f:3}]
```

to add object at 0 index

```
posts.unshift(post);//posts = [{a:1},{b:3},{f:3}]
```

to add object at last index

```
posts.push(post);//posts = [{b:3},{f:3},{a:1}]
```

to insert object at an index

```
posts.splice(1, 0, {g:8}); // posts = [{a:1},{g:8},{b:3},{f:3}]
```

and you can use _.mixin of course.

```
 _.mixin({
   push: function(arr,obj){
       return arr.push(obj);
   }
 });
```

and you can use it like

```
 _.push(posts,post);
```

[JsFiddle for mixin example](https://jsfiddle.net/kmsxsxwq/)

Answer (score 1):

Please try [_.fill](https://lodash.com/docs#fill), fills elements of array with value from start up to

> `_.fill(array, value, [start=0], [end=array.length])`

```
_.fill([4, 6, 8, 10], '*', 1, 3);
// → [4, '*', '*', 10]
```